# Authenticate using access key on server

Tags: facebook, rest, authentication, oauth

I want to create a chat application with two forms of login, a standard login form with username and password, and a secondary method using single sign in for logging in using facebook, but the user only needs to specify a username.

I'm planning on designing the application in two parts, a server side module which will be my own custom rest api, and an android application module.

I would like a way to authenticate the user from the server side. I was thinking of having the android application send an facebook api access token to my server, and then having my server check if it works for accessing their private data, but I'm unsure if this is valid enough proof that it is the original user. Is there a more standard way of checking if a the facebook user is who they say they are?